# Negative look behind RegEx extract all matches

Tags: python, regex

Extract all matches where "horse" is not preceded by more than 2 alphabets within a word or extract whole word matches after a word boundary.

The horse sat on the deck => ['horse']

The horse is playing with other horses => ['horse']

Number 900horse is the best one => ['horse']

Number 900ahorse is also a good one to bet on => ['horse']

Number 900abhorse is also a good one to bet on => []

horseabc => []

Tried this but doesn't seem to work:

`re.findall(r"(?<![^a-z]{2})(horse)\b", colName)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem existed in `[^a-z]`, by adding `^` you meant, match `horse` if two preceding characters were `not` from `[a-z]`

All we had to do was to remove the `not` as follows:

`(?<![a-z]{2})horse\b`

Suggestion: [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/) is a great online regex visualizer and explainer, to understand your regular expressions and debug them

Answer (score 2):

The character class should be without the `^` or else it would be negated.

You can omit the capturing group as there will be matches only.

```
(?<![a-z][a-z])horse\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GHJxi0/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/WH347D)